# Change window size to fit current image size with feh from CLI

Tags: display, feh

I have read the feh manual but could not find a command line option to change window size to fit current image size :

```
$ qrencode -o- https://youtu.be/JrLYOJqe22U | feh --zoom 300 -
```

Can you help me ?

Answer (score 2):

By default, feh will set the window size to the input image's resolution.
You can do a quick test by augmenting the module size `-s` in qrencode which augments the size of the QR code image:

```
$ qrencode -o- https://youtu.be/JrLYOJqe22U | feh -
```

vs

```
$ qrencode -s5 -o- https://youtu.be/JrLYOJqe22U | feh -
```

In case you would like to have a fixed window size, you can set feh to do so with `-g` and make it zoom the image to fit the window with `--auto-zoom` and `--scale-down`

```
$ qrencode -o- https://youtu.be/JrLYOJqe22U | feh --auto-zoom --scale-down -g 600x600 -
```

You will notice that the scaling will cause the QR code to be blurry, so augmenting the module size will make the image sharper even if scaled:

```
$ qrencode -s20 -o- https://youtu.be/JrLYOJqe22U | feh --auto-zoom --scale-down -g 600x600 -
```

**TL;DR**

Use `-g {resolution}`, `--auto-zoom` and `--scale-down` with feh to set the desired window size of your image and it will get scaled to fit.